# sql code to include values where sums of them is not 0

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sum

I have a code that should be pulling data for items that have sum not equaling 0. However, my code doesn't seem to work 100% of the time (having sum(amount) ! = 0). it is still pulling values per item that in aggregate are 0 when using having !=0 syntax.

Could you please help to understand why this is happening? Thank you for all your help!

I have also tried to use <> 0, however, getting different result as certain values per item that have a single line item are excluded from that query results.  For ex:

```
A  1000
B   200
B  -100
```

By running

```
having sum(amount) <> 0
```

it will only give me values in B and will not show values in A. Not sure why.

Comment: showing the code would be easier. So you have select letter, sum(amount) from X group by letter having sum(amount) <> 0. correct?

Comment: We really need to see a query in order to help with this. This sort of thing is often a logic error in how the SQL is written.

Comment: How do you expect us to help with with `having sum(amount) <> 0` as the only code?

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
select item
from t
group by item
having sum(amount) <> 0;
```

Are you saying this doesn't work?  If not, could you set up a db fiddle of some sort with sample data.

Comment: Hi Everyone! Thank you very much for your help! I figured out the issue.  it was in my syntax.